# How to implement a Function1 in Java (its compose and andThen methods)?

Tags: java, akka

I am working with Akka Java API's, in one of the actors I want to receive a callback and process it on completion.

I want to achieve something like:

```
Future future = Patterns.ask(actorRefMap.get(order.getInstrument()), order, 500);
future.onComplete(getSender().tell(String.format("{} order processed for instrument {} with price {}", order.getOrderType(), order.getInstrument(), order.getPrice()), getSelf()), getContext().dispatcher());
```

With my current code I am getting error wrong first argument, Found 'void' required 'scala.Function1'. How do we implement the `scala.Function1` in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it as a function:

```
Future future = Patterns.ask(actorRefMap.get(order.getInstrument()), order, 500);
future.onComplete(() -> getSender().tell(String.format("{} order processed for instrument {} with price {}", order.getOrderType(), order.getInstrument(), order.getPrice()), getSelf()), getContext().dispatcher());
```

... the essential part is:

```
future.onComplete(() -> ...)
```

instead of

```
future.onComplete(...)
```

And if it requires `scala.Function1` instead of `java.util.Function`, make sure you import the Java DSL (`akka.actor.typed.javadsl.AskPattern`), not the Scala DSL ...